# How to set an $error in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

How to set an error like the form validator does in `laravel 5.6`? I am still confused on how to set this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return redirect('redirect-url')->withErrors('Error msg here');
```